# Django change name of image from ImageField

Tags: python, django, image, dynamic, django-models

I would like to change the name of an image coming renaming it to the color of the door.

**Here is my code**:

```
class Door(models.Model) :
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='doors')
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='119.99')
```

I've looked at multiple things but I don't know yet how to do it.
Please help me if you know the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    filebase, extension = filename.split('.')
    return 'images/%s.%s' % (instance.color.name, extension)

class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Door(models.Model) :
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='119.99')
```

Comment: Worked absolutely perfectly! Thank you so much

Comment: filebase? Could you explain it?

Comment: The split function with dot divide the filename string in two parts. We set first part in filebase and second part in extension.

Comment: Just be careful here. A filename with more than one dot '.' will cause a ValueError: Too many values to unpack exception. for example, "bob.smith.jpg" would throw an exception

Comment: yeah, I changed my strategy

Comment: As Sam mentioned, split('.') is not cool. It's better to use os.path.splitext(filename) here.